# Counter in Collections module Python

Tags: collections, counter, python-import, importerror, python-2.6

I've come across a really weird problem. I'm trying to use Counter function in collections module. However, I keep getting the same error message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'
```

I have tried using it before and it worked fine, but now for some reason when I import "collections" module it has a very limited number of attributes.

I have tried:

```
import collections   # when calling Counter I would then use collections.Counter()
import collections as collect # collect.Counter()
```

For both of those I keep getting Attribute Error.

I have also tried

```
from collections import Counter
```

And in this case I got:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

These are all tested both in ipython interface and through a script (not importing anything else, just the collections).

Any ideas?

Comment: In general when dealing with this sort of unexpected behaviour, it is often a good idea to make sure the module is the one you think it is.  So try import collections;print(collections) and make sure it is the standard library version.  I've seen this sort of issue crop up when either the python path gets screwed up or a library gets added to the python path that has the same name as a standard library.

Comment: make sure your file name should not be "collections.py" otherwise you will face consequences.

Answer (score 27):

The `Counter` class was added to the module in Python 2.7. You are most likely using Python 2.6 or older. From the [`collections.Counter()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> *New in version 2.7.*

On python 2.5 or 2.6, use [this backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) instead.

Comment: I'm facing same issue in Python 3.0 as well, `'module' object has no attribute 'Counter'`: `print(collections.Counter({'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':1}))`

Comment: @KamalNayan you’ll need 3.1 or newer. 3.0 is really ancient and I *very, very strongly* urge you not to use it. The Python 3 series started to become really great at 3.4 and newer. 3.0 has some serious performance issues for example.

Comment: I'm beginner to python and is getting my hands dirty on different versions. I don't know what was issue on that windows PC (using py 3.0), it was not working, but same is working on my other windows system (on 2.7 and 3.6 both). I'll check on py 3.6 on my former PC.

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same issue while installing `pandas`.

**Cause**: `Counter` is only supported in `python2.7` and higher and is not available in earlier versions - `Counter` class got added into `collections` package in `Python 2.7`.

---

**Solution 1**: As stated by Martin Pieters - use the backport.

Add [`counter.py`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) at `/lib64/python2.6/` - this is where the `collections.py` is `./lib64/python2.6/collections.py`
Patch `collections.py` with:

```
from counter import Counter
```

**Solution 2**: use the [`backport_collections`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backport_collections/0.1) package.
Next patch (the import statement) the package you're getting exception at i.e. pandas in my case:

```
from backport_collections import Counter
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using an old version of Python, the `Counter` class, as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was added in version 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a new version of python AS python 3. You can then use this module.
Then import,

```
import collections
from collections import counter
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has the same issue - check that you have not named the file you are working on "collections.py". In some IDEs (including PyCharm) if you try to import the collections module into a file you've named collections.py, it won't work.

Your file will try to import itself into itself, so the contents of collections (including Counter) will not be imported.

You can resolve this by renaming your current file to anything other than collections.py.