# count in defaultdict(list) python

Tags: python

I am not able to get it working without your help. I want to filter some syslog messages based on devicename. The output should look like this.

```
Device1: 1x failure1,50 x failure2, 20x failure3
Device3: 10 x failure1,5 x failure2, 2x failure3
```

Code:

```
frequencies = defaultdict(list)

word = ['syslog1error1','syslog1error2','syslog1error3']

def findpattern():
    for line in syslog:
            if re.search(r"regexforhostname",line):
                hostname= line.strip()[16:27]
                for failure in word:
                    if failure in line:     
                    frequencies[hostname].append(failure)

x = findpattern()

print frequencies
```

Output looks like

```
'Devicename':'syslog1error1', 'syslog1error1', 'syslog1error2', 'syslog1error3'
```

I would like to count the double entries in the list. But I can't get it running with import collections (counter)

Please help.

Comment: *But I can't get it running with import collections (counter)* What happens when you try to import `collections.Counter`, exactly?

Comment: Are you on something below Python 2.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counter in Collections module Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13311094), depending on what your error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) (see [Counter in Collections module Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311094/counter-in-collections-module-python) if you are on a Python version < 2.7):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def findpattern():
    frequencies = defaultdict(Counter)

    for line in syslog:
        if re.search(r"regexforhostname",line):
            hostname= line.strip()[16:27]
            frequencies[hostname].update(f for f in word if f in line)

    return frequencies

result = findpattern()
for device, frequencies in result.iteritems():
    print '{}: {}'.format(
        device, 
        ', '.join(['{}x {}'.format(c, f) for f, c in frequencies.most_common()]))
```

Comment: Typo - `collections.Counter()`. :)

Comment: +1 for Counter and refactoring to return the dict. I'd put the initialization of frequencies into findpattern.

Comment: @SukritKalra: Yeah, holdover from Plone; I mistype `collections` for `collective` too. Thanks for pointing that out, fixed!

Comment: Thanks for you help. It works but I received a lot of garbarge from device which I have not don't care. I only want to see the devices which have a valid entry in the word list. 

I did the following and it works but I don't know if this programmed nicely. 

    for device, frequencies in result.iteritems():
 if len(frequencies) is not 0:

Comment: You can just use `if frequencies:`; empty containers (including `Counter` objects) are considered False in a boolean context such as an `if` statement.