# Any pythonic way to do "[['a', 2], ['b',1]] + [['b', 2], ['c', 1]] = [['b', 3], ['a', 2], ['c', 1]]"?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

input:

```
[['a', 2], ['b',1]] (sorted by value)
[['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

output:

```
[['b', 3], ['a', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

Any pythonic way? Of course, in Python! (better for 2.6x)
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a dict?

Comment: Do you want to do this using list alone ?

Comment: Coz, the output will encode to JSON. And, most of time, the system just need the top one. Anyway, this is a interesting question, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for Python2.7+:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lis1 = [['a', 2], ['b',1]]
>>> lis2 = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
>>> c = Counter(dict(lis1)) + Counter(dict(lis2))
>>> c.most_common()
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

If the lists contain repeated items then you need to modify the `Counter` example to this:

```
>>> lis1 = [['a', 2], ['b',1], ['b',5]]
>>> lis2 = [['b', 2], ['c', 1], ['a', 10]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = sum((Counter(dict([x])) for x in chain(lis1, lis2)), Counter())
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 12), ('b', 8), ('c', 1)]
```

For 2.5 <= Python <=2.6 use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k, v in lis1 + lis2:
    d[k] += v
...     
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: Add: map((lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]), t) at last?

Comment: @Kane: `map(list, whatever_you_called_the_output)` if you want lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

As no `Counter` class in collections for [python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13311111/1265154), this one is will do. One can use `defautldict`, but its usage do not simplifies code:

```
a = [['a', 2], ['b', 1]]
b = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
rv = {}
for k, v in a + b:
    rv[k] = rv.setdefault(k, 0) + v
```

Ouput of expected result, converting to list of lists:

```
>>> map(list, sorted(rv.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
[['b', 3], ['a', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this answer in here but, you *may* wish to combine them to a list, and then count them:

```
>>> a = [['a', 2], ['b',1]]
>>> b = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
>>> a + b
[['a', 2], ['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
>>> "".join(c*n for c, n in a+b)
'aabbbc'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("".join(c*n for c, n in a+b))
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
>>> Counter("".join(c*n for c, n in a+b)).most_common()
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create dicts out of your list of tuples(lists here in your case), and then add their counters.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
>>> b = [['a', 2], ['b',1]]
>>> sorted(dict(Counter(dict(a)) + Counter(dict(b))).items(),key= lambda x:-x[1])
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice

> > > from collections import Counter
> > >
> > > lis1 = [['a', 2], ['b',1]]
> > >
> > > lis2 = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
> > >
> > > c = Counter(dict(lis1)) + Counter(dict(lis2))
> > >
> > > c.most_common()

```
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

collections.defaultdict in python 2.5 and 2.6  and collections.Counter in 2.7 and later

> > > from collections import defaultdict
> > >
> > > d = defaultdict(int)
> > >
> > > for k, v in lis1 + lis2:

```
d[k] += v
```

> > > sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

```
 [('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> p = [['a', 2], ['b',1]]
>>> q = [['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
>>> m = Counter(dict(p)) + Counter(dict(q))
>>> sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```