# django ImportError: cannot import name Counter

Tags: django, pip, easy-install

I got old django project. I am getting error

> ImportError: cannot import name Counter

when try to runserver. What i did:

1. Created virtualenv.
2. Installed requirements: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
3. Tried to `python manage.py runserver` and got that import error.
4. Tried `pip install Counter`, but still same error.

What is strange, console doesn't say anything else about error, just this one line. What could it be?

EDIT:
Also strange, there is no `Counter` app in requirements.txt

Comment: Did you add it to the installed_apps ?

Comment: Now i did, but still same. I don't even know if projects uses that app

Comment: https://github.com/KelSolaar/Counter            Here is the source. In usage, you have to call Counter() method. Maybe check your project and find usages of it. If you didn't use it just delete. Maybe there is a compatibility issues or you've missed something we still don't know.

Comment: Counter class is new in Python 2.7 class. Maybe your Python version might be old, therefore it can't import it.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311094/counter-in-collections-module-python

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: There is no traceback, just this line.