# How to count occurrences of key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.6

I know this is a frequently asked question, however I do not have access to the Counter module as I'm using v2.6 of Python. I want to count the number of time a specific key appears in a list of dictionaries.

If my dictionary looks like this:

```
data = [{'a':1, 'b':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'b':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'd':1}]
```

How would I find out how many times "a" appears? I've tried using len, but that only returns the number of values for one key.

```
len(data['a'])
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: I've updated post to include my "attempt", which I know is incorrect.@chrisz

Comment: BTW, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13311111/4014959), there's a [backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) of Counter for Python 2.5 & 2.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```
data = [{'a':1, 'b':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'b':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'd':1}]
sum([1 for d in data if 'a' in d])
```

*Explanation:
First take the dictionary object from list data, check if key 'a' is present in the dictionary or not, if present, add 1 to the list. Then sum the new list.*

Answer (score 2):

You won't have access to **`collections.Counter`**, but **`collections.defaultdict`** was added in Python 2.5

**`keys`** and flatten list

```
data = [j for i in data for j in i.keys()]

# ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']
```

**`collections.defaultdict`**

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(int)

for key in data:
  dct[key] += 1

# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1})
```

If you only need the count for `a`, there are simpler ways to do this, but this will give you the counts of all keys in your list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

A one-line solution could be:

`len([k for d in data for k in d.keys() if k == 'a'])`

Answer (score 0):

This question looks very much like a class assignment.  Here is a simple bit of code that will do the job:

```
n=0
for d in data:
   if 'a' in d:
       n+=1
print(n)
```

Here `n` is a counter, the `for` loop iterates through the list of dictionaries.
The `'a' in d` expression will return true if the key 'a' is in the dictionary d, in which case the counter n will be incremented.  At the end the result is printed.  I believe in Python 2.6 the brackets would be optional (I am using 3.6).

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Could you say a few words about why this works and is and answer to the OP's situation?

Answer (score 0):

For this you could write the following function that would work for data in the structure you provided (a list of dicts):

```
def count_key(key,dict_list):
    keys_list = []
    for item in dict_list:
        keys_list += item.keys()
    return keys_list.count(key)
```

Then, you could invoke the function as follows:

```
data = [{'a':1, 'b':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'b':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'c':1}, {'a':1, 'd':1}]
count_a = count_key('a',data)
```

In this case, count_a will be 4.