# Grab recurring IP from log and write to new document or log

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find IP addresses in read.log that are listed more than 3 times.
Once found, I want to print the IP address once and write it to writelist.log.

I have been trying this using a set but I am not sure how I can print and write only the IP address.

For example, if read.log contains...

```
10.1.89.11
255.255.255.255
255.255.255.255
10.5.5.5
10.5.5.5
10.5.5.5
10.5.5.5
255.255.255.255
255.255.255.255
```

I just want to print and save the below to writelist.log

```
255.255.255.255
10.5.5.5
```

With my current code, I am printing and saving this...

```
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set(['10.5.5.5'])
set(['10.5.5.5'])
set(['10.5.5.5', '255.255.255.255'])
```

I do not want to print `set([])` or duplicate IP addresses.

I know I could use the `string.replace()` method to get rid of some of that but is there a better way to do this? Possibly without a set?

Here is my code...

```
import re

login_attempts = 3

def run():

    try:
        with open("read.log", "r+") as log:
            ip_list = []
            for line in log:
                address = "^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$"
                match = re.match(address, line)

                if (match):
                    match = match.group()
                    ip_list.append(match.strip())
                    s = set([i for i in ip_list if ip_list.count(i) > login_attempts])

                    strs = repr(s)  # use repr to convert to string
                    with open("writelist.log", "a") as f:
                        f.write(strs)

                else:
                    continue
                log.close
    except OSError as e:
        print (e)

run()
```

Comment: This seems like a good use case for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @JohnB Yes and for some reason I can't find a good answer to link here. If you find one let me know and I'll dupe it.

Comment: I did see an example using that earlier today.  I'll read up on it.

Comment: @KadeWilliams you can read the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections
with open('read.log', 'r+') as f:
     # Place into a counter and remove trailing newline character
     count = collections.counter(f.read().splitlines())
```

Which will give

```
Counter({'10.1.89.11': 1, '255.255.255.255': 4, '10.5.5.5': 4})
```

You can then iterate over the `Counter`

```
for ip, n in count.items():
    print(ip, n)
    # Process the IP
    ...
```

This assumes that you're receiving clean input. You will have to sanitise your data before you process it.

Comment: And to conditionally output, you could iterate over `count.items()` and only write if greater than 3.

Comment: You could also avoid that inner loop and do `f.read().splitlines()`. It should be noted though that by stripping the new line, remember to add it when writing back each line you want to the new file too.

Comment: For completion sake you can show the write part. Per the comment, the trick here is that you still need to call `items` on `count` just like @JohnB mentioned.

Comment: Would this still work well if there was other data in the log?  There may be other text other than IP addresses.  I'm running 2.7 and 3.6 but getting errors in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311094/counter-in-collections-module-python

Comment: AFAIK, anything < 2.7 isn't supported. you'd have to show your new code and what errors you're getting

Comment: @KadeWilliams mentioning that there might be other data in the logs changes the entire nature of the question and invalidates what is a good answer based on the information provided. Also, if you are using 2.7 then you should not be receiving that error (you also tagged your question as python-3.x). Are you sure you are not on 2.6? This is also information that would be good to add to the original question. Since you need to extract the IP as well since you have other data, you will most likely need your regex that you have to create your list, then use your counter method.

Comment: You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496518/python-using-a-dictionary-to-count-the-items-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer for more methods on how to count occurrences.